# Use two attributes to fill part of one multipolygon that is inside of another

Tags: qgis, style

I have one vector layer that contains two mutipolygons (simplified version). Polygon 1 is the National Park boundary, Polygon 2 is the forested areas.

Can I style the forested area differently depending on whether it's inside or outside of the National Park boundary?

I tried setting a style for forested areas inside the NP:

```
"boundary" = 'National Park boundary' AND "landuse" = 'forest'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use Rule based styling with the queries

**Forests within parks**:

`"type"='forest' and overlay_within(layer:='areas', filter:="type"='national_park')`

**Forests outside parks**:

`"type"='forest' and not overlay_within(layer:='areas', filter:="type"='national_park')`

[image]

Comment: I guess this does not work in cases where forest polygons span across park categories, does it ? In which case an intermediate Geometry Generator layer might be an option

Comment: It doesn't work when the forest polygon is partly inside and outside of the national park. My national park areas are using a fill colour, so one solution is to duplicate the layer and then multiply the NP over the forested area. This results in 3 duplicate layers that are styled differently. Lay1 - for fills, Lay 2 - for NP (multiplied), Lay 3, linework and boundaries (this is because I have hill shading multiplied over the fill layers and I don't want it to affect the linework.

Comment: Within only works if it is within or not within. You can use other overlay functions like `overlay_intersects`. Or maybe you should color by wether the centroid of the forest is within/outside national parks